# What is the overhead for large SDL2 Textures vs. many small SDL2 Textures?

Tags: c++, c, sdl-2, processing-efficiency, memory-efficient

1. You can set up SDL2 to import one large image file as a single Texture, then use SDL_RenderCopy() to splice into that Texture into the sections where individual images are needed.
2. You could also import many smaller image files as Textures and use those individually.
3. I think you can also import the large image file and split it into multiple Textures.

Do these different methods of handling Textures have times when one is clearly a better option? Like with the last example, I imagine there would be a significant slowdown at the startup of my program, but could it become more efficient as my code continues to call Textures that have already been processed?

I don't have any code to accompany this question. Mostly I'm really just curious about how SDL2 handles Textures on an almost hardware level.

Comment: I would agree with your assertion, that with many small textures from files startup time could increase while with splicing large textures you _might_ have a marginal runtime overhead. I'd recommend going with the scenario, that promises better code readability and maintainability. Because that is what you want in the long run.

Comment: Oh and SDL2 is actually also just a wrapper around OpenGL / Software rendering, depending on what option you use for your window creation.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/186647/does-sdl2-completely-encapsulates-direct3d-and-opengl) over at stackexchange / gamedev.

Comment: I think the most important gain from bundling textures have nothing to do with performance. It's about using 1 file for all the textures that belong together. Nicely organized. Instead of 1237 files if your project is large. For that same reason, bundling literally **all** textures together seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! So if I understand correctly, there will be a difference in the methods, but there is no way of knowing the exact difference without looking at the OpenGL/DirectX/whatever underpinnings the computer in question is using anyways. If I care about a (closer to) hardware level of precision, I should just use OpenGL/DirectX/etc. directly, and not worry about it with SDL. Neat!

Comment: I would expect a single large texture to be faster, or at least not slower. At least in OpenGL, switching between many small textures has overhead.